# WPF expander troubles

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I used many expander in the WPF application.. but I face some troubles:

- When I try to put them below each others, the upper one expands automatically and makes it difficult to put the net one below it.. So I should separate the upper one in any place until I put the lower one then move back the upper one again. Can I keep expander unexpanded to make it easy to put any controls below it?
- When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> and expand one of them, I see it has a transparent background and makes interruption with the lower ones - how can I avoid that?
- I used scroll bar inside expander, but it doesn't work when i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>. I have an inactive scroll bar.  How can I make link between scroll bar and expander to be able to move items inside expander up and down?

This is a picture to explain what I mean. [image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/iIXKLbnQ/q_online.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at ths tutorial, it covers stuff like this, The Expander can be a tricky control to deal with sometimes, but once you understand the the expanders layout it becomes a bit easier.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/02/03/taming-the-wpf-expander-control.aspx